# Python Selenium Timeout Exception Catch

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

In my threads I use a simple variable either set to '1' or '0' to indicate if it is ready to go again. Trying to debug an issue where sometimes this isn't being reset and I think I might have it.

I didn't want connections timing out into some infinite load time (I believe the default for Selenium is not to have a timeout) so I used:

```
Driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
```

And later on in that thread I would check

```
If condition:
 isrunning = 0
```

I had originally thought that the set_page_load_timeout would just stop it loading after 30 seconds but if I'm understanding this correctly it would actually throw an exception so I'd need to do something like:

```
try:
  Driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
except:
  isrunning = 0
  Driver.Close()

-Do whatever else in function -
If condition:
  isrunning = 0
  Driver.Close()
```

So if it ran over 30 seconds it would close and set to 0 otherwise it would run on and get checked and set to 0 later.

I appreciate this is a tiny snippet of code but the full thing is pretty long winded and I think that's the important part.

I'd appreciate it if someone could confirm I have the right idea here. I'm all up for doing the testing but it's a problem which occurs once every 8 hours or so making it hard to pick apart but I think this potentially fits.

Comment: a lot of text, but what is a question?) How to intercept `TimeOutException` or what?

Answer (score 76):

Almost of your code is working fine except the `Driver.Close()`. It should be `Driver.close()`. The `TimeoutException` will be thrown when the page is not loaded within specific time. See my code below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

Driver = webdriver.Firefox()
try:
    Driver.set_page_load_timeout(1)
    Driver.get("http://www.engadget.com")
except TimeoutException as ex:
    isrunning = 0
    print("Exception has been thrown. " + str(ex))
    Driver.close()
```

Comment: In my code there is `except TimeoutException:`. However, in case of `selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: xxx` the exception is not caught leading to printing `Traceback (most recent call last):`, `Stacktrace:`, and `Backtrace:` followed by abnormal exit of the Python script. Why? How to correctly catch this exception?

Comment: @pmor I think your error is outside of try/catch. Please check the line number that throws the error.

Comment: Thanks! I thought that Selenium provides access to a partial DOM (hence, I do `page_source` even in case of `TimeoutException`), however, it [doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45237189/1778275).

Answer (score 1):

this should work

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

try:
    Driver.set_page_load_timeout(1)
    Driver.get("http://www.engadget.com")
except TimeoutException
    pass
isrunning = 0
Driver.close()
```