# Can we get page source using Selenium even it's not fully loaded (TimeoutException: Message: timeout)?

Tags: python, selenium, automation

Can we get page source even we meet (TimeoutException: Message: timeout)?

When I call "driver.page_source", it sometimes failed to load full pages.

But I only need partial information of it which is not determined yet. So I just want to save the page in any cases. Is it possible?

```
import random

def info_request(driver,project_id,project_url,path):
    driver.get(project_url)
    sleep(0.2+random.uniform(0, 1.5))
    doc = driver.page_source
    with open(str(project_id)+ ".html", "w") as f:
        f.write(doc.encode("utf-8"))
    return project_info

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(40)
driver.set_page_load_timeout(40)

project_info = info_request(driver,project_id,project_url,path)

driver.close()
```

Comment: The short answer is no. Selenium does not provide access to a partial DOM. Recommend increasing `page_load_timeout`. This will not necessarily increase the script execution time, but will allow pages more time to load, if needed. To increase script reliability, you could wrap the `doc = driver.page_source` and following code with a try/except block so that even if a timeout occurs, other tests can be run without the script running into an exception.

Comment: @RonNorris - I think you should be putting that as an answer to this question rather than a comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no. Selenium does not provide access to a partial DOM. Recommend increasing driver.set_page_time_out(). This will not necessarily increase the script execution time, but will allow pages more time to load, if needed. To increase script reliability, you could wrap the page_source and following code with a try/except block so that even if a timeout occurs, other tests can be run without the script running into an exception.

```
import random

def info_request(driver,project_id,project_url,path):
    try:
        driver.get(project_url)
        # sleep(0.2+random.uniform(0, 1.5))
        doc = driver.page_source
        with open(str(project_id)+ ".html", "w") as f:
            f.write(doc.encode("utf-8"))
        return project_info
    except TimeoutException:
        return "Timeout"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(40)
driver.set_page_load_timeout(120)  # Or your preferred patience factor

project_info = info_request(driver,project_id,project_url,path)

driver.close()
```

Comment: So, what is the long answer? Is it possible _somehow_ to collect DOM until the timeout is expired and then to save the collected DOM?